# Android Qt How can I set an qml image source to a generated svg?

Tags: android, qt, qml

Where should I save my custom generated svg in order to be able to access it in qml.
What I have seen is that qml Image component requires the image source to be in 
"assets:/...". Is there another path to save my svg, or can I do something to locate it somewhere else?

Comment: Have you looked at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/resources.html. Basically wherever you put it, make sure the resources.qrc file references it correctly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Retrieving the path using QUrl::fromLocalFile(generatedSvgFilePath) (not only QString or QUrl(string) ) made it work.

generatedSvgFilePath = QCoreApplication::applicationDirPath() + "/" + fileName;

Answer (score 0):

You are not required to use "assets:/..." Assets is a lot like resource files, but specific to Android.

What you want is a writable location on the Android device to store your generated SVG files. You can use the QStandardPaths class to obtain the path to such a folder:

```
QString path = QStandardPaths::writableLocation(QStandardPaths::AppDataLocation);
QFile output(path + "/myfile.svg");
(...)
```

On my device, this ends up placing data in the folder "/data/data/com.myDomain.myAppName/," which is perfectly fine, but it is a pain in the rear for debugging purposes because unrooted Android won't let any other apps open that folder for browsing to let you see what your app has been doing.

Therefore, it might make some sense to temporarily use the shared Download folder for debugging purposes. On my Android device, this is "/storage/emulated/legacy/Download/," but that specific path may be different on your device. I believe the following will return the path to the shared Download folder that your device uses:

```
QString path = QStandardPaths::standardLocations(QStandardPaths::DownloadLocation)
```

The downside of using the shared Download folder is that any files your app generates in there will not be cleared off the device when your app is uninstalled. Conversely, files stored in the AppDataLocation folder will be automatically removed by the system whenever your app is uninstalled.